# Handling Slack (Event API) events in a Symfony application

Tags: php, symfony, events, slack-api

I'm trying to get events on my Symfony webapp when a new message is posted in a specific channel. Nothing too fancy, maybe storing the message in my MySQL database or simply displaying it. My true problem is that I don't really know where to start, how to handle the event or how to manipulate the data sent by Slack.

So far I've scoured Slack API's documentation but it doesn't provide language-specific guidelines (unlike Google's API for example). I've managed to register my Ngrok-fed URL (I'im in local development for now) to receive events and can see that my server is indeed receiving requests and payloads, I just don't know how to handle them. Really, I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction to get started.

I am receiving the Slack payload from a GET request and I can see the Slack message I'm trying to retrieve, but I don't know how to use it in my web application.

I have a function defined to the route I set on the Slack API to receive events:

```
/**
 * @Route("/slack/handshake", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function getSlackHandshake () {

    $rawData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $event = json_decode($rawData, true);

    if (isset($event['challenge'])) {

        $response = new Response(
            $event['challenge'],
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['content-type' => 'text/plain']
        );

        return $response->send();
    } else {

        $response = new Response(
            '',
            Response::HTTP_OK
        );

        // return $response->send();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('slack_test', array('message' => $rawData));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Please don't put code in a image, just paste the code in your question. What do you want to do? Store the data then show it?

Comment: Just a guide to handling the event in my code would be great, like how to store it in a variable and send it to a view or something like that!

Comment: See the Doctrine documentation: [persist](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) and [fetch data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database).

Comment: I know how to access my database with Symfony, my question is about how to correctly implement events in a Symfony app and how to use data that I received through the Slack Event API

Comment: I'd recommend anonymising your data before posting questions as there is the potential to get sensitive information. It's quite easy to find tokens/keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you're getting everything over GET on your /slacktest route (which apparently you don't provide code for).

essentially you should trust symfonys dependency injection / auto-wiring:

```
public function slacktestAction(Request $request) { // <-- request added!
    // since the url is /slacktest?message=... the message is retrieved via
    $urlParam = $request->query->get('message'); 

    // the message is JSON so:
    $decoded = json_decode($urlParam, true);

    // your message is slightly buried:
    $message = $decoded['event']['text'] ?? null;

    // $message should now contain "Testing for new message"

    // now you can do whatever you want with this.

    return new Response('');
}
```

(`Request`/`Response` require a use clause after the namespace: `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;` - and for `Response` accordingly)

just in case you're wondering, the url-encoded message in your log is (pretty printed for readability):

```
{
  "token": "SOME TOKEN",
  "team_id": "SOME TEAM ID",
  "api_app_id": "SOME APP ID",
  "event": {
    "client_msg_id": "message-ida-sauniq-ueid",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Testing for new message",
    "user": "USER-NAME",
    "ts": "1563280049.003900",
    "team": "SOME TEAM ID",
    "channel": "SOME CHANNEL ID",
    "event_ts": "1563280049.003900",
    "channel_type": "channel"
  },
  "type": "event_callback",
  "event_id": "SOME EVENT ID",
  "event_time": 1563280049,
  "authed_users": [
    "SOME USER ID"
  ]
}
```

and json_decode(...,true) turns this into an array. as far as I can tell, almost anything that is slack api is json encoded.

however, the [actual events api](https://api.slack.com/events-api) (and specifically the [message spec](https://api.slack.com/events/message)) is quite clear, IMHO. some fields apparently are not documented, but can be safely ignored, I guess

Comment: Yes sorry I realized I hadn't posted the code for the other function, but it's just a one-line function receiving a $message parameter and doing a dd($message). So far I've been learning PHP by basically printing everything through dd() and figuring out what I need to do from there :D

Comment: the handshake seemed to be sophisticated enough, so maybe I made some assumptions about ability level ;o)

Comment: I think the POST request contains my Slack token and such information, but I'm not 100% (not even 10%) sure about that. I'll take a look at what you gave me and will come back to update this! Thanks!

Comment: @acante yeah, I looked into it, it essentially only verifys the url you gave to slack and is irrelevant later on. the "magic" happens in the slacktest / GET requests.

Comment: i think my problem is that i'm not quite sure how to react to the event i'm receiving. i'm trying to just print the $message variable so i can check what's inside - how would i go about and do that?

Comment: @acante the point is, your server is talking to slack, and that doesn't have anything to do with you(r browser, and its request). that means, the slacktest route must store it somewhere (perhaps db) so you can then - on another route - read it. just storing shouldn't be a problem, reading neither. the question is, what is it you want to store, the json, the serialized array, a custom object. but actually, your question is quite broad if you don't have any plan for what you want in the end...

Comment: okaaaay so i guess the answer to my question is that the data i receive from the event, i must store in order to access it in other parts of my code? that makes sense i guess! thanks!